# How to disable ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes for bitnami/zookeeper chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I have deployed the bitnami/zookeeper chart (i.e. https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/zookeeper/11.3.1) on my aws cluster.

As per the document its showing deprecated Ref - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/zookeeper#to-8-0-0

But, if you see the below screenshot, you can find

> ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes

How to disable this or change this to "No"?

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the helm chart code:

```
 - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
   value: {{ ternary "no" "yes" .Values.auth.client.enabled | quote }}
```

It seems like it is controlled with `.Values.auth.client.enabled`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but not working.